# How to make a centered div container that can stretch vertically based on the elements inside?

Tags: css, html, stretch

I'm brand new to this and I'm trying build a simple layout of divs.  I'd like to have 3 container divs:  header, content, footer.  The content div I don't want to have the height fixed, I want it to stretch based on whatever is inside of it.  Also I don't know javascript so I want to do it with HTML/CSS only.

I've looked on this site for answers, but they don't seem to work.  Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="header" style="background:beige;">
        <div id="logo" style="background:gray;">
          put logo here 
        </div>
        <div id="navigation" style="background:grey">
          About Us, Contact Us, Etc....
        </div>
    <div id="content" style="background:beige;">
        <div id="bigbox" style="background:black; color:white;">
          big box would have some slide show here
        </div>
        <div class="smallbox" id="smallboxleft" style="background:green;">
          smallboxleft
        </div>
        <div class="smallbox" id="smallboxmiddle" style="background:green;">
          smallboxmiddle
        </div>
        <div class="smallbox" id="smallboxright" style="background:green;">
          smallboxright
        </div>
    </div>    


        <div id="footer" style="background:navy; color:white;">
          This is the footer
        </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
  #header{margin:0 auto; height:100px; width:960px; position:relative; }

  #logo{height:100px; width:200px;}

  #navigation{height:50px; width:400px; position:absolute; left:560px; top:50px;}

  #content{margin:0 auto; width:960px; height:100%; position:relative; top:25px;}

  #bigbox{position:absolute; height:300px; width:860px; position:absolute; left:50px; top:125px;}

  .smallbox{position:absolute; height:150px; width:300px; top:450px;}
  #smallboxmiddle{left:320px;}
  #smallboxright{left:640px; }

  #footer{position:absolute; height:100px; width:960px; top:625px;}
```

Comment: How exactly do the answers you've found _not_ work?

Comment: I dont know if its intensional or typo, why you place the content into the header. The header should be closed first, then the content should start.

Comment: aaamos, the one I remember is making the height 100%.  And thats not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend (mrlostman) has given me the answer:

> don't specify height
> and make #content { overflow : hidden }
>
> when you have floated elements, they stop pushing their containers down.  perhaps you felt >the need to specify height because of this ( #content would always stop short).
>
> overflow:hidden is an accepted way around this
>
> also creating an empty div just before the end of the container with { clear:both; >float:none; } would do the trick; but this way is not preferred

So, for #content, I simply modified to:  height:auto; overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 2):

I usually end up using [`display: inline-block`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display) when I want an element to "shrinkwrap" to its contents.

> `inline-block` makes the element generate a block box that’s laid out as if it were an inline box.

Comment: Thanks but by adding that code to #content, it didn't help.  #content is gone now and everything else below it is now on the left.  Sorry for my lack of knowledge of what's actually happening, this is just what I see.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the width of your content div to auto. width: auto; and to get around other issues with this add "clearfix" as a class to your content div and add this inside of your css..

```
 .clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

And anytime you want the same idea applied to your div just add the clearfix class to it.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but its doing the same thing as what the above answer did.

Comment: then you're not applying it correctly. This will solve your issue

Comment: you also do not have an ending body tag and an ending div tag on your header... not sure if that was just a pasting error

Comment: Your code is very much broken once you correct these errors in your code.

Comment: Maybe my code is broken, thanks for your help.  I'll keep working on it.